# Optimising while loops in C?

Tags: c, while-loop

Is there a better way to write the following while loops in C

```
while (x > 0 && x <= 16)
    // do this
while (x > 16 && x <= 32)
    // do that 
while (x > 32 && x <= 48)
    //do this
while (x > 48 && x <= 64)
    //do that 
while ( x > 64 && x <= 80)
    //do this
```

.... and so on

I have to go up to a ridiculous high number and I was wondering if there is any better way to do this? I am new to coding so any suggestions would help.

Comment: Are all the "do this" the same as each other (and likewise all the "do that")? That is, are you alternating between 2 actions, each being done 16 times, or in the example above, are there really 5 different actions?

Comment: yes i am alternating between 2 actions

Comment: Can you please give some specification of 'do that' here ?

Comment: I am trying to turn a light on and off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment, you're doing one of two actions depending on which range x falls into as a multiple of 16. Note that:

```
x   | (x-1)/16 | ((x-1)/16)%2
----+----------+--------------
1   |    0     |       0
15  |    0     |       0
16  |    0     |       0
17  |    1     |       1
31  |    1     |       1
32  |    1     |       1
33  |    2     |       0
50  |    3     |       1
68  |    4     |       0
... |   ...    |      ...
```

So you can use `((x-1)/16)%2` to determine which action to do:

```
while (x < ridiculous_high_number) {
    if (((x-1)/16) % 2 == 0) {
       //do this
    }
    else {
       //do that
    }
}
```

Comment: I *think* `x` is mutable *within* each loop of do-this or do-that, but it is admittedly difficult to tell with the posted question. Now that I think about it, it must be or the loops would never break. So I think this is pretty solid, since that will just pass control to the alternate code block on the next iteration, but the increment should be removed from the for-loop. nice answer.

Comment: This answer does the trick my light is blinking. :) thank you very much.

Comment: This is an infinite loop but the OP's code isn't. Presumably it's the OP's code that's wrong, so this is better than an optimization.

Comment: @JimBalter: by that reasoning, the OP's code is also an infinite loop. there's nothing in his loops which modifies the value of `x`

Comment: "by that reasoning" -- I merely stated a fact; you seem to be missing my point. Obviously the OP *does* modify `x` in the this/that code. Once the 5th loop terminates, subsequent code is executed. But your code loops regardless of whether `x` is modified.

Comment: Ok, there aren't just 5 loops, because the OP says "and so on" -- but what the heck does that mean? Eventually the OP will run out of loops. Your code loops forever. It's not clear whether it should, or whether the OP wants it to stop at some point.

Comment: @JimBalter: hmm ok. updated the loop to reflect the question more

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal:

```
for (;;)
{
    if ((x - 1) % 32 < 16)
        do this
    else
        do that
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
for ( int k = 0; k <= yourRidiculousHighLowerBound; k += 16 ) {
    while ( x > k && x <= k + 16 ) {
        if ( k % 2 ) {
            // do that
        }
        else {
            // do this
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if you didn't mean `this` and `that`s are the same... Then I'd need more information.

<sup>**edit:** Well, after looking at the other answers, this appears to be the only answer that does exactly what has been asked; others differ in the exact behaviour. Apparently the question wasn't reflecting what OP was asking for, oh well =/</sup>

Comment: Why ThisNiceVariableName model?

Comment: @Jack It's not a variable name, it's a descriptive phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's just my own little oddity, but for cases like this, I find it perfectly reasonable to use an array of pointers to functions, and use the relevant bit to index into that array:

```
void turn_off() { /* ... */ }
void turn_on() { /* ... */ }

typedef void (*func)();

func f[] = {turn_off, turn_on};

for (int x=1; x<whatever; x++)
    f[((x-1) >> 4) & 1]();
```